# How to disable page scroll in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

What css style should I use to disabel scroll in Internet Explorer.
I already tried:

```css
body, html 
{ 
    overflow-x:   hidden; 
    overflow-y:   auto;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: if you are  trying to disable horizontal-scroll then use  `overflow-x:   hidden;`
else foe disabling vertical scroll use `overflow-y:   hidden;`

Comment: Try setting height:100%,width:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This trick as I apply on my code once

```
<body scroll="no">
```

You could also try setting the overflow property of the html page in CSS like so.

```
html, body { overflow: hidden; }
```

This CSS works for me both in Chrome and IE 10:

```
/* Oculta la scroll-bar pero sigue permitiendo hacer scroll con el mouse */
    body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;  }
    html, body { -ms-overflow-style: none; overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser scroll can only be disabled if your page height is not greater than windows height. So to disable scroll you need to designed your side as frame type. you can use `position: fixed` to your section and show one section at a time and rest on `mousescroll` (just an option).